# Strange behaviour ArrayList.remove();

Tags: android, listview, indexing, adapter

I am running into a issue and i can't seem to solve it on my own.

I am trying to remove a item from a listView with .remove(postion); and .notifyDataSetChanged(position); But it is removing the wrong position.

Here is my code

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        try {
            ViewHolder holder;
            final String[] parts;
            final String uuidbeacon;
            uuidbeacon = arrayL.get(position).getProximityUuid().toString();
            minorbeacon = arrayL.get(position).getMinor();
            rangebeacon = arrayL.get(position).getAccuracy();
            parts = fetchTums(uuidbeacon).split("::");

            if (convertView != null) {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            else{

                if(parts[0].equals("1")) {
                    holder = new ViewHolder(convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tupple_monitoring, null));
                    holder.beacon_image.setImageDrawable(getTumImage("http://127.0.0.1/uploads/face/" + parts[4]));
                    holder.beacon_uuid.setText(parts[1]);
                    holder.beacon_txpower.setText(String.valueOf(position));
                }
                if(parts[0].equals("0"))
                {
                    holder = new ViewHolder(convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tupple_monitoring, null));
                    holder.beacon_txpower.setText(String.valueOf(position));
                    toRemoveString = toRemoveString + String.valueOf(position) + "::";
                }
                if(parts[2].equals("1"))
                {
                    holder = new ViewHolder(convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tupple_monitoring, null));
                    holder.beacon_image.setImageDrawable(getTumImage("http://127.0.0.1/uploads/face/" + parts[4]));
                    holder.beacon_uuid.setText(parts[1]);
                    holder.beacon_txpower.setText("Hier misschien wat text?");
                    holder.beacon_row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#B6B6B6"));
                    holder.image_lock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }
            if (arrayL.get(position).getProximityUuid() != null)


            list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id )
                {
                    //list.setItemChecked(position, true);
                    //view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

                   final String[] parts;
                   parts = fetchTums(arrayL.get(position).getProximityUuid().toString()).split("::");

                   if(parts[2].equals("1")){

                       pin(parts[3], parts[1]);
                   }
                   else{
                        if(parts[3] != null){
                            openPage(parts[3], "", parts[1]);
                        }
                   }
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return convertView;
    }
```

The part above works fine i get a list view with 2 items position 0 and 1 and i know the items have the correct postion i write the position in them in a textview.

The function to remove a item is:

```
public void toRemoveFunc()
{
    arrayL.remove(0);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

it is called on a button click.

But what happens now is strange when i click the button it will remove the item with position 1 and if i click it again it will remove the item with position 0. if i change arrayL.remove(0); to arrayL.remove(1); it will remove the item with position 1 and if i click again it crashes as expected. But what i really want is remove postion 0 and keep position 1.

Comment: have you tried debugging by putting a breakpoint at arrayL.remove(0) and seeing what elements does arrayL have prior to removing and in which order?

Comment: @dora I don't know what you mean exactly but i took a screenshot of debugging you can see it here http://nl.tinypic.com/r/20rv48m/8 (Cant show the picture in the post need 10 rep :/)

Comment: `holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();` what do you think this does? (hint: you never call `setTag`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working, but after converting the "convertView" you are not updating its values.

```
ViewHolder holder;
        final String[] parts;
        final String uuidbeacon;
        uuidbeacon = arrayL.get(position).getProximityUuid().toString();
        minorbeacon = arrayL.get(position).getMinor();
        rangebeacon = arrayL.get(position).getAccuracy();
        parts = fetchTums(uuidbeacon).split("::");

        if (convertView != null) {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        else{
holder = new ViewHolder(convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tupple_monitoring, null));
}
            if(parts[0].equals("1")) {

            holder.beacon_image.setImageDrawable(getTumImage("http://127.0.0.1/uploads/face/" + parts[4]));
                holder.beacon_uuid.setText(parts[1]);
                holder.beacon_txpower.setText(String.valueOf(position));
            }
            if(parts[0].equals("0"))
            {

                holder.beacon_txpower.setText(String.valueOf(position));
                toRemoveString = toRemoveString + String.valueOf(position) + "::";
            }
            if(parts[2].equals("1"))
            {

                holder.beacon_image.setImageDrawable(getTumImage("http://127.0.0.1/uploads/face/" + parts[4]));
                holder.beacon_uuid.setText(parts[1]);
                holder.beacon_txpower.setText("Hier misschien wat text?");
                holder.beacon_row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#B6B6B6"));
                holder.image_lock.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
```

Comment: How do you mean? I see my list view item disapear from the screen but its the wrong one

Comment: While reusing the views, your "convertView" is the second one, and you are not updating the values inside of the view. Update your code as my answer.